# __MonoCS__ does not work in mono 5.0. How to determine platform at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, build, mono

This code is broken after upgrading to mono 5.0:

```
#if __MonoCS__ //Linux...
        var mode = LZ4StreamMode.Compress;
#else //Windows...
        var mode = System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress;
#endif
```

What constant can I use as a replacement ?

Comment: Due to the recent changes in Mono, to be more compatible to .NET Framework, I wonder whether you really now need to use such conditional compilation any more.

Comment: I need those conditions for interactions with unmanaged code and other platform specific features in big project. I understand a workaround with "DefineConstants", but does Roslyn define some special platform dependent constants? (As I understand, mono project was migrated to Roslyn compiler in 5.0).

Comment: I'm having this problem too. And this is due to Mono not fully implementing some property in an SQL Data Parameter and under Mono I need to define it, but not under .Net compiler. Now I can't tell... It will be OK to remove this if they fully support all properties and methods of everything in .Net. But that's not the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet, this link requires authentication...

Comment: @LexLi, I was trying to make a dirty fix for code using System.Deployment.Application. (I know you shouldn't do that, but there was a bunch of other 'wrong' events leading to this being seemingly optimal solution)

Comment: @ironic: Hmm - I'm afraid I don't know whether there's an unauthenticated way of seeing the details. (I can't remember the details now.)

Answer (score 0):

[this is noted in the release notes for mono 5.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/) as well as the reasoning:

> Note: mcs defined the **MonoCS** symbol and some users incorrectly used it to conditionally compile code specific to Mono. This is considered bad practice and won’t work anymore now that csc is the default compiler. You can detect whether you’re running on Mono at runtime instead.